# Select the table rows by default based on the data in antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm new to antd and I'm stuck at one place in my project. I want to check/select the checkboxes of rows by default based on the sourcedata or data.

for example if i have the datasource as

```
const data =
[ 
{
key: "1",
name: "John",
age: 22,
chosen: true,
working: null
},
{
key : "2",
name: "Jason",
age: 23,
chosen: false,
working: 'John'
}]
```

So based on datasource if any object has chosen key as true, I want to check/select the checkbox of those rows by default.

I can filter out the data array depending on the chosen key has the value true or not. But how to check the checkbox by default? Is there any prop for the antd table, which will take the array of filtered data and check/select the checkbox for those rows?

I tried to check the rows using checked attribute inside getCheckboxProps but when I use that in console I get a warning saying "Warning: [antd: Table] Do not set `checked` or `defaultChecked` in `getCheckboxProps`. Please use `selectedRowKeys` instead."

Below is the code which I'm currently using.

```
const data =
[ 
 {
  key: "1",
  name : "John",
  age : 22,
  chosen: true,
  working: null
 },
 {
  key : "2",
  name: "Jason",
  age: 23,
  chosen: false,
  working: "John"
 }
]

const fiterSelectedRows = data.filter(row => {
        return row.chosen;
});

const rowSelection = {
        onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
            console.log(
                `selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`,
                "selectedRows: ",
                selectedRows
            );
        },
        getCheckboxProps: record => {
            return {
                disabled: record.working != null,
                name: record.working
            };
        }
};

<Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data}/>
```

Comment: Lo necesitaba, gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice `selectedRowKeys: data.filter(item => item.chosen).map(item => item.key)`. `selectedRowKeys` contain all keys of items, all items have keys in here will be checked by default.

You need to get all items that have `chosen` is true.

```
data.filter(item => item.chosen)
// [{key: '1', name: 'John Brown', ...},
//  {key: '3', name: 'Joe Black', ...},
//  {key: '4', name: 'Joe Black', ...}]
// all items have chosen is true
```

Then get all keys of this array.

```
data.filter(item => item.chosen).map(item => item.key)
// ['1', '2', '3']
// all keys of items have chosen is true
```

Exmample code:

**Data**

```
const data = [{
  key: '1',
  name: 'John Brown',
  age: 32,
  chosen: true,
  address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '2',
  name: 'Jim Green',
  age: 42,
  chosen: false,
  address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '3',
  name: 'Joe Black',
  age: 32,
  chosen: true,
  address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '4',
  name: 'Disabled User',
  age: 99,
  chosen: true,
  address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
}];
```

**Datatable**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedRowKeys: data.filter(item => item.chosen).map(item => item.key), // Check here to configure the default column
    loading: false,
  };

  start = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    // ajax request after empty completing
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        selectedRowKeys: [],
        loading: false,
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  onSelectChange = selectedRowKeys => {
    console.log('selectedRowKeys changed: ', selectedRowKeys);
    this.setState({ selectedRowKeys });
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, selectedRowKeys } = this.state;
    const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys,
      onChange: this.onSelectChange,
    };
    const hasSelected = selectedRowKeys.length > 0;
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={this.start} disabled={!hasSelected} loading={loading}>
            Reload
          </Button>
          <span style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}>
            {hasSelected ? `Selected ${selectedRowKeys.length} items` : ''}
          </span>
        </div>
        <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what this.selectRow(record) is doing in onRow prop for table?

Comment: Yes, the state will get all the data where chosen is true. But I want the checkboxes to be checked by default if chosen is true. how can I achieve that? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I put the example code in here [https://codesandbox.io/embed/priceless-ramanujan-dkygk](https://codesandbox.io/embed/priceless-ramanujan-dkygk). Check `selectedRowKeys: data.filter(item => item.chosen).map(item => item.key)` in line 65. This container all keys of checkboxes have chosen is true.

Comment: Yeah, the code works fine if chosen is true and it will select the rows by default. There is an issue where I can not check the checkbox of a row if a chosen is false or uncheck the checkbox if it is already checked. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: You need using component for this phase. First, add `selectedRowKeys` in component state with value is all keys of the item have `chosen`. Then you need to add function `onChange` that will change `selectedRowKeys` with a new selected key component pass to you. See the **Database** section in my code about for detail more.

Comment: I just update code in [https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-ramanujan-dkygk?fontsize=14](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-ramanujan-dkygk?fontsize=14). This is helpful for you.

Comment: Since I was using react hooks for storing the state I had to make a minor change in the code and it worked. Thank you so much for helping me Tran, really it was helpful. Much Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The author above said all the right things, I decided to share my experience. I have an array of objects with no key field (hello backend). Initially I filtered this array by a condition (depends on your task), for example, that the coin_symbol field === "WBNB". After filtering, I immediately use map to create a new array. Don't forget to make local state.

```
const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState()
setSelectedRowKeys(dashboardData?.filter(i => i.coin_symbol === 'WBNB').map(i => i.id))
```

Then, after digging in the table props, I saw a props defaultSelectedRowKeys, which takes an array. Further everything is simple - to this props assign value to our new array.

`const rowSelection = { defaultSelectedRowKeys: selectedRowKeys, ...otherProps (like onChange, getCheckboxProps, etc.)`

Another important thing - if you have, as I do, the data from the server go long, better not render a table, but rather, for example, some kind of loading text or a slider.

```
selectedRowKeys ? <YourTable dataSource={yourData} rowSelection={rowSelection}/> : <Loader/>
```

I hope it helps someone! (～￣▽￣)～